# how can i get IDLE (Python) to use packages installed by anaconda (windows 7 32bit)?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, python-idle

The title says it all i want to be able to use the packages that are installed with anaconda with idle so are there any ways of making this work?
When i try to import packages with idle that i installed using anaconda it says package not found.
I need some help please and thank you in advance.

Comment: It should work if IDLE is using the same version of python that you installed with anaconda.

Comment: idle is version 3.5.2 and anadaconda is 3.6.3

Comment: Well that's probably it. IDLE should be using the anaconda install of python.

Comment: how do i fix this ??

Comment: I don't use IDLE, but i imagine there is a setting where you can change the path the python install it's using.

Comment: @SuperStew Your comments are a bit backwards in that IDLE does not 'use Python'.  Rather, each python binary runs the IDLE in its own /Lib subdirectory.  So the question is how to get the anaconda python binary to run IDLE.  At least in part, the same ways you get any python binary to run IDLE.

Comment: @SuperStew Because IDLE (normally) runs user code in a separate process with a minimal amount of IDLE code, I have thought about the possibility of starting the user process with a different binary.  The problem is that a) IDLE would have to find out what other versions of Python are installed, and their location (not trivial), b) the different binary would have to use its own copy of idlelib (not a problem it itself), but c) the different version would have to communicate with the version running the IDLE gui, and I don't really want to freeze all current details.

Answer (score 0):

The IDLE that comes with python 3.5.2 can only be run by python 3.5.2.  Code you submit to python 3.5.2 through that IDLE can normally only access packages installed for 3.5.2, plus your own code.  I believe Anaconda 3.6.3 comes with Python 3.6.3 and the 3.6.3 standard library, including the 3.6.3 version of idlelib.

In order for your code to use the packages installed with anaconda, you must run your code with the anaconda binary.  To run your code from IDLE with the anaconda binary, you must run IDLE with that binary instead of some other binary (like the 3.5.2 binary.

When running Python 3.6.3 interactively, you can start IDLE 3.6.3 at a `>>>` prompt with `import idlelib.idle`.  If you can start python 3.6.3 in a terminal (Command Prompt on Windows), then adding the arguments `-m idlelib` will start IDLE.

On Windows, I have no idea whether or not Anaconda adds 'Edit with IDLE 3.6.3' to the right-click context menu for .py and .pyw files, the way the python.org installer does.  On any system, you should be able to create a file or icon that will start 3.6.3 with IDLE, but details depend heavily on OS and version.

Answer (score 0):

I see idle is automatically installed with Anaconda Python 3.
To launch idle open windows command prompt and type the below command:

> idle()

In my other laptop i can also launch idle by this command on windows prompt:

> python -m idlelib.idle

Hope this helps.
See this discussion for more info
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/Dr8xFdKbA20